# Give two points with the most similar distances to the origin

Tags: code-golf

Consider an \$(n+1) \times (n+1) \$ grid of points places at non-negative integer coordinates.  Given two points in the grid at \$(a, b)\$ and \$(c, d)\$, we know that the distance of the first point to the origin at \$(0, 0)\$ is \$x = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\$ and the distance of the second point to the origin is \$y = \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}\$.

Given a positive integer \$n\$, the task is to find non-negative integers \$0 \leq a, b, c, d \leq n \$ so that \$|x - y|\$ is as small as possible but **not** equal to zero.

## Input

Positive integer \$n\$

## Output

Two points \$(a, b)\$ and \$(c, d)\$ that minimize \$ |\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} - \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}|\$ under the constraint that \$ |\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} - \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}| \ne 0\$.

## Example

If \$n=7\$ then \$(7, 2)\$, \$(4, 6)\$ is a valid output.

Comment: What is the range of coordinates for the points in terms of n? If it's 0 to n then it's an n+1 grid.

Comment: Can output be in complex numbers?

Comment: @Tbw  No, sorry,

Comment: May we – in case of a tie – output _all_ eligible points? You write _two points_ so outputting three points also _includes_ outputting two points.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt yes that's ok

Comment: @Simd what is the rationale for not allowing complex representation?

Answer (score 9):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 114 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@Stefan Pochmann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/40544/stefan-pochmann)*

```python
lambda s:[r:=range(s+1)]*0+max([(e:=a*a+b*b)-c*c-d*d==1,e,a,b,c,d]for a in r for b in r for c in r for d in r)[2:]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY1BCoMwEEXX7SlmZxInUIVCCaQXsS4mibaBGiVaaM_SjRt7p96mqAVX__Hg896f7jXc2jBONWi4TI-hlqdvvFNjHEGviqh0pHCtWJ9mvBSHtKEnK1ilNAlKjTBcWmGlE07rDCskNGjRlXUbgcAHiDCj2dBu6BbkRa7Kfxln7Re9VDOE_MjVftdFHwbmERJ5ThBq5jlfP-O47g8)

Finds \$a, b, c, d\$ where \$(a^2+b^2)-(c^2+d^2)=1\$ and \$a^2+b^2\$ is maximal.

### Proof

The lower bound on difference between distances when \$(a^2+b^2)-(c^2+d^2)>1\$ is $$\sqrt{n^2+n^2}-\sqrt{n^2+n^2-2}$$ $$\sqrt{2n^2}-\sqrt{2n^2-2}$$ We can show points \$(n, 1)\$ and \$(n, 0)\$ always have distances closer than this lower bound with some simplification $$\sqrt{n^2+1^2}-\sqrt{n^2-0^2}<\sqrt{2n^2}-\sqrt{2n^2-2}$$ $$\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2}<\sqrt{2}\cdot(\sqrt{n^2}-\sqrt{n^2-1})$$ $$\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2}<\sqrt{n^2}-\sqrt{n^2-1}$$ The last statement is easy to see as \$\sqrt{x}\$ increases more slowly the further right in the \$x\$-axis we go, more formally the second derivative (change in slope) of \$\sqrt{x}\$ is always negative.

This means in the solution \$(a^2+b^2)-(c^2+d^2)=1\$ will always hold. Maximizing \$a^2+b^2\$ is also easy to see and also arises due the second derivatives of \$\sqrt{x}\$ being always negative.

Comment: Proof Request..

Comment: Checking with my code, it seems to be true for n up to 500. I'll probably work out a proof if I make a new answer with this idea.

Comment: Ok I don't feel like typing it all out formally so I'll put the gist in this comment. a^2 + b^2 and c^2 + d^2 are both at most 2n^2. If they differ by at least 2, then their roots differ by at least 1/(n*sqrt(2)) (by looking at the derivative of sqrt). The points (0,n) and (1,n) have distances that differ by sqrt(n^2+1)-n. Multiplying both expressions by n, we find that n*(sqrt(n^2+1)-n) is increasing and has limit 1/2 as n goes to infinity, never exceeding 1/sqrt(2). Therefore, a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2  must be 1. From there, it is obvious why a^2+b^2 is maximized.

Comment: 114: `lambda s:[r:=range(s+1)]*0+max([(e:=a*a+b*b)-c*c-d*d==1,e,a,b,c,d]for a in r for b in r for c in r for d in r)[2:]`

Answer (score 5):

## [Uiua 0.10.0](https://www.uiua.org/), 30 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Mar-9) (updated)</sup>

```
⍉⊟°ℂ⊏⊢⍏∩▽,⟜±⌵≡/-⌵.☇1⊞⊂.♭⊞ℂ.⇡+1
```

### Old solution, 32 bytes, faster

```
⍉⊟°ℂ⊏+⇡2⊢⍏≡/-◫2⌵.⊏⍏⌵.▽◰⌵.♭⊞ℂ.⇡+1
```

[Try on Uiua Pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4o2J4oqfwrDihILiio8r4oehMuKKouKNj-KJoS8t4perMuKMtS7iio_ijY_ijLUu4pa94pew4oy1LuKZreKKnuKEgi7ih6ErMQoKRiAxCiMjCkYgNDIKIyMKCkYgNwojIwoKNArih6ErMSAjIHJhbmdlIDAuLi5uCiMjCuKZreKKnuKEgi4gIyBncmlkIG9mIGNvbXBsZXggdmFsdWVzCiMjCuKWveKXsOKMtS4gIyByZW1vdmUgZHVwbGljYXRlIGxlbmd0aHMKIyMK4oqP4o2P4oy1LiAjIHNvcnQgYnkgbGVuZ3RocwojIwriiaEvLeKXqzLijLUuICMgZ2V0IGRpZmZlcmVuY2VzIGJldHdlZW4gYWRqYWNlbnQgbGVuZ3RocwojIwor4oehMuKKouKNjyAjIGdldCBpbmRpY2VzIGZvciBzbWFsbGVzdCBkaWZmZXJlbmNlCiMjCuKNieKKn8Kw4oSC4oqPICMgcGljayBhbmQgdHJhbnNsYXRlIGNvbXBsZXggdG8gcG9pbnRzCiMjCg==)

```
⇡+1      # range 0...n
♭⊞ℂ.    # grid of complex values
▽◰⌵.   # remove duplicate lengths
⊏⍏⌵.    # sort by lengths
≡/-◫2⌵. # get differences between adjacent lengths
+⇡2⊢⍏    # get indices for smallest difference
⍉⊟°ℂ⊏   # pick and translate complex to points
```

The new solution is slower because it makes a list of every possible pair of points, but otherwise it does much of the same.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŻŒċ⁺µ²§½ạ/ȯ1µÞḢ
```

A monadic Link that accepts \$N\$ and yields a pair of pairs of integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//xbvFksSL4oG6wrXCssKnwr3huqEvyK8xwrXDnuG4ov///zc)**

#### How?

Brute force, although I can't help but think some divisor-based logic could work.

```
ŻŒċ⁺µ²§½ạ/ȯ1µÞḢ - Link: positive integer, N
Ż               - zero-range {N} -> [0..N]
 Œċ             - unordered pairs, with replacement -> points above or on y=x
   ⁺            - repeat -> all pairs of those points (up to reordering)
    µ       µÞ  - sort these pairs of points by:
     ²          -   square all the values
      §         -   sum each pair of squares
       ½        -   square-root these two values
        ạ/      -   reduce by absolute difference
          ȯ1    -   logical OR with 1 (replace zeros with ones)
              Ḣ - head
```

Comment: A non brute force solution would be awesome. It seems that one of the four variables is always n as well although that might need a proof.

Comment: @Simd `22` seems to be the first counterexample.

Comment: Oh well, that's a shame.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 14 bytes

```
z:Ẋ:Ẋⁿλ²Ṡ√/ȧ1∨
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJ6OuG6ijrhuorigb/Ou8Ky4bmg4oiaL8inMeKIqCIsIiIsIjMiLCIzLjQuMiJd)

Pretty much just the trivial solution. Uses Jonathan Allan's trick for avoiding returning zero values (well, this is just a port of Jonathan Allan's solution, but it's pretty much straightforward).

#### Explanation

```
z:Ẋ:Ẋⁿλ²Ṡ√/ȧ1∨    Full Program
z                 0..x
 :Ẋ               Cartesian Product with itself (gives a list of points)
   :Ẋ             Cartesian Product with itself (gives a list of pairs)
     ⁿλ           Minimum by lambda:
       ²          - Square (vectorized)
        Ṡ         - Sum Each
         √        - Square Root (vectorized)
          /ȧ      - Reduce over Absolute Difference
            1∨    - || 1 (if 0, replace with 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 108 bytes

Returns `[a,b,c,d]`.

This is based on [Mukundan314's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271663/58563).

```javascript
n=>eval(m="for(i=++n**4;i--;a*a+b*b+~(x=c*c+d*d)|x<m||(m=x,o=A))A=[a,b,c,d]=[1,0,3,2].map(j=>i/n**j%n|0);o")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY1NCoMwGAX3niIIhfxp1XYXP8FziIuYaIloIioi1Pbqabp6sxjmjfKQm1rNsifW6d4P4C1U/SEnPEM8uBUbYMxS@hQmSYSkknW0Y198gqKKaarJdZbzdQX95A5qQmpoJO@44rqFJucZf/CiTWe54BEqcw@t8WavjAgXE/9/mPodWQQoF2FKQEUWgDGC3hFCytnNTX06uRe2HA3YEiKij/8B)

Comment: Assuming your code is correct, 1, 12, 8, 9  seems to be the answer for n between 12 and 50 at least! Can that be right?

Comment: Ah no that's a bug. That gives a difference of 0 which is not allowed

Comment: Not really a bug, but rather a floating point rounding error.

Comment: So `Math.hypot` is less accurate than manual square roots? That seems suboptimal.

Comment: @Neil It depends on the implementation. Both functions give the same results on Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 98 bytes

```hs
f n=tail$minimum[e:l|l@[a,b,c,d]<-mapM id$[0..n]<$"four",e<-[abs$sqrt(a^2+b^2)-sqrt(c^2+d^2)],e>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcfRCsIgFADQX7kMH4p0jL0E4UY/0BeIg@tUuqS21L317zY6b@eJ5eVCaM1DmipSYJESxT0qdwvfcFfIDV@51VJE3B5Alqmh75OWrPPvPXfcSaHQFFY@uZ5wGS9mGc/iv/WYPaa5mwfdIlKCCbZMqQIDD9f2Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>54</s> 43 bytes

```
≔⊕ＮθＩΦ⌈ＥΦＥ…Ｘθ³Ｘθ⁴↨ιθ⁼¹↨Ｅ⪪Ｘι²¦²Σλ±¹⮌⊞ＯιΣＸι²κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY29DsIwDIR3noLRkcrQwtYJEEgMlIo@gSlWiUjTND/A2wcHEDAk8V3uPrcXtO2AKsalc7LTsNOtpZ60pzPPJvgq9CeyIEQ2HUU5qa3UHtboPGyl8vyzx4fsQ8@v@VkGjqg7gnq4sx6z6Zz7X7FItBU6ApmoLDZjQOUg/9gJ0Bgl/QfAsUK8T8OrVKpU1KEnyIVI6kg3stysg7scDFn0w6uW4n8M8U5f@S5jLIo4u6kn) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Even more brute force than before, but still a port of @Mukandan314's Python answer.

```
≔⊕Ｎθ
```

Input `n` and increment it.

```
Ｅ…Ｘθ³Ｘθ⁴↨ιθ
```

Convert the range from `(n+1)³` to `(n+1)⁴` into base `n+1` so the results all have four base-`n+1` digits `d`, `c`, `b` and `a`.

```
Φ...⁼¹↨Ｅ⪪Ｘι²¦²Σλ±¹
```

Filter on those where `a²+b²=c²+d²+1`.

```
Ｅ...⮌⊞ＯιΣＸι²
```

For each of those, prefix `a²+b²+c²+d²` to `a,b,c,d`.

```
ＩΦ⌈...κ
```

Output the `a,b,c,d` with the maximum sum of squares.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <del>132</del> <del>96</del> 68 bytes

Saved 36 bytes thanks to @lesobrod,
Saved 28 bytes thanks to @att

---

68 bytes version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b737Eo3TczL7o63dYxqTjaL78o16G6QqeyVhfCrNKpjdVJtzOwsU20sVWu1Um0BcnqAIV1PPNKUtNTi4pj1f4HFGXmlTikOZj/BwA)

```mathematica
ArgMin[{g=Abs[Norm@{x,y}-Norm@{z,}],g>0<=a<=#},a={x,y,z,},Integers]&
```

96 bytes version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcmxCsIwEIDhhykUhdN2c0hPrqOg4l46nJLGG3JCElBb8uyR4vbz/Z7T03pO8uAyYdkoVoZx@cAXZnhn47C/x@H6Cp5WzLt/rm803OzPHBNdRMXLbIfFgTu20HZYdah1Q5yB4aTJOhviuK3LLYgmmuhQfg)

```mathematica
ArgMin[{g=Abs[Norm@{x,y}-Norm@{z,}],g>0<=a<=#},a={x,y,z,},Integers]&
```

132 bytes version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcs9C8IwFIXhvxI6pldQF0EbJxeHguB4uUi@qhdsijEulv722Eqm5z3D6XV6@F4ntjrnDsON9qod3OfpcYyq5cA9f@e@vmJCLXVtpKHVf1lpaycdwbpRulFh0RRt0S2W27EcJhg1GLAw1zkkf/fxTRNExC0R5dOAl8ghIUMlRAUdMpEQMDJsYDfRIf8A)

```mathematica
f[n_]:=Module[{r=Minimize[{Sqrt[a*a+b*b]-Sqrt[c*c+d*d],0<=a<=n,0<=b<=n,0<=c<=n,0<=d<=n,a*a+b*b>c*c+d*d},{a,b,c,d},Integers]},r[[2]]]
```

Comment: The outputs are not correct. Check you get the same answer for n=7 as in the question.

Comment: @Simd Thanks, I have corrected the code.

Comment: I am afraid it is still largely wrong. Look at the answer you should get from https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//xbvFksSL4oG6wrXCssKnwr3huqEvyK8xwrXDnuG4ov///zc .

Comment: @Simd Sorry, now the correction is done.

Comment: Same idea, but [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcmxCsIwEIDhhykUhdN2c0hPrqOg4l46nJLGG3JCElBb8uyR4vbz/Z7T03pO8uAyYdkoVoZx@cAXZnhn47C/x@H6Cp5WzLt/rm803OzPHBNdRMXLbIfFgTu20HZYdah1Q5yB4aTJOhviuK3LLYgmmuhQfg)

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b737Eo3TczL7o63dYxqTjaL78o16G6QqeyVhfCrNKpjdVJtzOwsU20sVWu1Um0BcnqAIV1PPNKUtNTi4pj1f4HFGXmlTikOZj/BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>82</s>60 bytes

-22 bytes thanks to @att!

```
MinimalBy[Range@#~Tuples~{2,2},N[r={1,-1}.Norm/@#]/Sign@r&]&
```

Significantly different approach from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271669/114511), so separate post.
As is customary in Codegolf *we don’t have to be efficient in performance or running time*.
So here just brute-force selection from all possible tuples. So answer is also all possible combinations,
eg for input `7` output is `{{{2, 7}, {4, 6}}, {{2, 7}, {6, 4}}, {{4, 6}, {2, 7}}, {{4, 6}, {7, 2}}, {{6, 4}, {2, 7}}, {{6, 4}, {7, 2}}, {{7, 2}, {4, 6}}, {{7, 2}, {6, 4}}}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7875@WFh2QX55aZGWVmZdWGcsFEvDMS8vMyyypBImlpJbEcqXZ/vcFiuQm5jhVRgcl5qWnOijXhZQW5KQW11Ub6RjV6vhFF9lWG@roGtbq@eUX5eo7KMfqB2em5zkUqcWq/Q8oyswrcUhzMP8PAA)

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7875@WFh2QX55aZGWVmZdWGcsFEvDMS8vMyyypBImlpJbEcqXZ/vcFiuQm5jhVRgcl5qWnOijXhZQW5KQW11Ub6RjV6vhFF9lWG@roGtbq@eUX5eo7KMfqB2em5zkUqcWq/Q8oyswrcUhzMP8PAA) (:

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 100 bytes Mukundan314's method

```javascript
n=>(m=g=(a,b,c,d)=>(a?g(a-1,b,c,d):1)/d?a*a+b*b+~(x=c*c+d*d)|x<m||(o=[a,b,c,d],m=x):g(n,a,b,c))()&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBDoIwEEWvworMtEXtFhw5iHFRWpjUQMeAMSyIV6/EsHnJfz/v6T5u8XN8vaskoc8D5UQ3mIgJnOmMNwH37VoGV9lD1BbPoXXK6U51@gsreeV1UAG39TptGwjdj/hhJlqxZkjmbxABy1LyIDNwJNsUHK/20hRac0QvaZGxP43C@2uKYSdi/gE)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 113 bytes

```javascript
n=>(m=g=(a,b,c,d)=>(a?g(a-1,b,c,d):1)/d?(v=(h=Math.hypot)(a,b)-h(c,d))>m|v<=0||(o=[a,b,c,d],m=v):g(n,a,b,c))()&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxNCoMwEIWv4kpmMFqzVUdP4AlKF6k/SYpmRCVQ8O6pFjcP3vd@PsqrrVvtsqeO@yGMFBzVMJMmUOItOtHj6VWjQaXyBoXER9@AJzDUqt1k5rvwjtcAUwNXBev58BXlxwFMz/vpJWbyWGhw4k8QAeOYw8graEuyjLStZF5GSaItduw2noZsYn2mIhpPRQw/)

+1 byte like Arnauld's if some issue

```javascript
n=>(
  m=                     // Last Length
  g=(a,b,c,d)=>
    (a?g(a-1,b,c,d):1)   // g(a-1,b,c,d) would return a positive number
    /d?                  // if d is number
      (v=(h=Math.hypot)(a,b)-h(c,d))
                         // Compare length
      >m|v<=0||          // Require it positive. Negative mean (c,d,a,b) is positive
      (o=[a,b,c,d],m=v)  // Update
    :g(n,a,b,c)          // Nest layer
)()&&o                   // Output
```